# SSAS Cube Dimension Hierarchy hide Members based on member value?

Tags: ssas, mdx

I am building a dimension hierarchy where I want to hide some child members based on their values.

There is a built-in function in the property part called `HideMemberIf` that allows me to Hide child members that `OnlyChildWithParentName` or `OnlyChildWithNoName` and etc..

I am wondering if there is also an advanced option that allows me to write an expression to hide certain member.

Comment: When you say "based on their values" this is not possible in MDX. A member does not have a single value. You have to look at all the dimensions to see what value it might have (for example, one member might have value `10` when date is `2019` and location is `Spain` and product is `Bicycle`).

Comment: So please give an example of what you want to happen.

Comment: @Magnus Smith For example, if the product dimension has a hierarchy with root members like `Cars`,`Bicycle`,`Airplane` and within `Bicycle` I have `Road` and `Mountain`, `Others`. what I want the do is to hide the `Others` type from the users. Thanks for the help though, I was stuck with the dimension itself, later on, I realize that I can solve the problem by using a query instead of the source table in `DSV`.